# Kibana 6 merging 2 filters

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I have 2 filters that work well :
1. Matches to the phrase "NA"

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "region.keyword": {
        "query": "NA",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2.Uses a scripted field that pulls filters to show all hours not between 0-7:

```
{
  "script": {
    "script": {
      "inline": "boolean gte(Supplier s, def v) {return s.get() >= v} boolean lt(Supplier s, def v) {return s.get() < v}gte(() -> { doc['@timestamp'].date.hourOfDay }, params.gte) && lt(() -> { doc['@timestamp'].date.hourOfDay }, params.lt)",
      "params": {
        "gte": 0,
        "lt": 7,
        "value": ">=0 <7"
      },
      "lang": "painless"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to group this into one filter so its "NA hours not between 0-7" this way I can change the region and the times and still apply additional filters.

Also not sure how to add this kinda custom filter as adding a filter only allows me to put in 1 field

Answer (score 1):

Before you make use of visualizers and discover, make sure that you create index pattern under **`Management -> Index Pattern -> Create index pattern`**` and add the name of the index on which you'll be applying filters.

Now, combining the queries you've added in the question, the combined query would be something like below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "region.keyword": {
            "query": "NA",
            "type": "phrase"
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "boolean gte(Supplier s, def v) {return s.get() >= v} boolean lt(Supplier s, def v) {return s.get() < v}gte(() -> { doc['@timestamp'].date.hourOfDay }, params.gte) && lt(() -> { doc['@timestamp'].date.hourOfDay }, params.lt)",
              "params": {
                "gte": 0,
                "lt": 7,
                "value": ">=0 <7"
              },
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Discover Section

In [Discover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html) section of Kibana, select the index name in **`index pattern section`(refer to the link for the image)** and then click on `Add a filter`, there in the right side you would see an option `Edit Query DSL`.

Copy and paste the above query. You should be able to see the results in `Document Table` i.e. the document details under the graph.

### Visualizer

Well you have not mentioned in the question if this is related to a particular visualizer(or discover tab), however just like the way we've added filter in discover section, you can do so in the [visualizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/visualize.html) as well (say for e.g. in `Metric Visualizer` where you'll see `Edit Query DSL` section under `Add a filter`)

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This is pretty helpful though I got this error ` [parsing_exception] no [query] registered for [region.keyword], with { line=1 & col=646 }` which is strange because it works fine when the script isnt joined. I finds the region.keyword just fine.

Comment: @chowpay, I've tried using a sample mapping and used its `field.keyword` and it works fine at my end. Including with script. Could you try to isolate the issue using basic `match` with `range.keyword` as well as with other fields and see if that works in the `Edit Query DSL`. Also remove `"type": "phrase"` in the first query you have. Check if at first both queries returns response via Kibana and then merge them.